# Move from stack to heap

Tags: c++, c++11, move

I'm trying to call some function that includes adding element to vector ( argument passed by value ):

```
std::vector<Val> vec;   
void fun( Val v )
{
  ...
 vec.push_back(std::move( v ));
 ...
}
```

The question is: are there any benefits from move **semantics**?

I'm confused about variable will be "moved" from stack to heap when new vector element constructing: it seems it will be just copied instead.

Comment: `std::move` is only a cast.

Comment: @liliscent Yeah, I know. I'm interested about vector move constructor behaviour in this situation

Comment: It depends on how `Val` is implemented. If it makes good use of move semantics you gain something, otherwise you don't. As the author of `Val` you should try to make good use, otherwise you don't care.

Comment: `std::vector`'s move constructor has nothing to do with it because it is a `Val` that is being moved, not a `std::vector`.

Comment: @nwp Let's assume Val is std::shared_ptr. Seems it's OK to move shared pointers, and could improve performance sometimes. I'm confused about moving stack variable to heap exactly

Comment: When they say "move" they really mean "copy with stealing from the original". A copy will be made inside the `vector` that is allowed to steal the resources of `v`. In this case it allows saving incrementing the reference counter by instead making `v` point to nowhere and thus keeping the total number of `shared_ptr`s pointing to that object constant.

Comment: @nwp yep, but vector's move constructor can't use shared_ptr allocated on stack, as it needs allocate it on heap, isn't it?

Comment: Again, `vector`s move constructor is never used. `shared_ptr`s move constructor is used. Heap or stack doesn't matter.

Comment: @nwp, my fault, I mean when ptr is moved to vector via `push_back`, how could heap-allocated ptr steal the reference counter from stack-allocated ptr?

Comment: You just do `shared_ptr(shared_ptr &&other) { pointer = other.pointer; other.pointer = nullptr; ref_count = other.ref_count; other.ref_count = 0; }`. You can express that somewhat better with `std::swap`, but that's the basic idea.

Comment: @ nwp Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If std::move allows the underlying objects to move pointers from one to the other; rather than (what in done in copying) allocating a new area, and copying the contents of what could be a large amount of memory.  For example

```
class derp {
    int* data;
    int dataSize;
}
```

data & dataSize could be just swapped in a move; but a copy could be much more expensive

If however you just have a collection of integers; moving and copying will amount to the same thing; except the old version of the object should be invalidated; whatever that should mean in the context of that object.

Comment: What do you mean by "the old version should be invalidated"? How do you invalidate an `int`? Also arguably `derp` and `std::vector<int>` are just a collection of integers, yet moving and copying them are very different.

Comment: @nwp how do you invalidate an int?  It's the *object* you invalidate; not the individual members.  So an int as you say can't be; but if that int represents the datasize like above then having it 0'ed might make sense; and having data (again as above) set to nullptr makes even more sense.

Answer (score 3):

Whether there is any benefit by moving instead of copying actually depends on `Val`'s implementation.

For example, if `Val`'s copy constructor has a time complexity of *O(n)*, but its move constructor has a complexity of *O(1)* (e.g.: it consists of just changing a few internal pointers), then there could be a performance benefit.

---

In the following implementation of `Val` there can't be any performance benefit by moving instead of copying:

```
class Val {
    int data[1000];
...
};
```

But for the one below it can:

```
class Val {
    int *data;
    size_t num;
...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

A move is a theft of the internal storage of the object, if applicable. Many standard containers can be moved from because they allocate storage on the heap which is trivial to "move". Internally, what happens is something like the following.

```
template<class T>
class DumbContainer {
private:
    size_t size;
    T* buffer;

public:
    DumbContainer(DumbContainer&& other) {
        buffer = other.buffer;
        other.buffer = nullptr;
    }

    // Constructors, Destructors and member functions
}
```

As you can see, objects are not moved in storage, the "move" is purely conceptual from container `other` to `this`. In fact the only reason this is an optimization is because the objects are left untouched.

Storage on the stack cannot be moved to another container because lifetime on the stack is tied to the current scope. For example an `std::array<T>` will not be able to move its internal buffer to another array, but if `T` has storage on the heap to pass around, it can still be efficient to move from. For example moving from an `std::array<std::vector<T>>` will have to construct `vector` objects (`array` not moveable), but the `vector`s will cheaply move their managed objects to the `vector`s of the newly created `array`.

So coming to your example, a function such as the following can reduce overhead if `Val` is a moveable object.

```
std::vector<Val> vec;   
void fun( Val v )
{
    ...
    vec.emplace_back(std::move( v ));
    ...
}
```

You can't get rid of constructing the `vector`, of allocating extra space when it's capacity is filled or of constructing the `Val` objects inside the `vector`, but if `Val` is just a pointer to heap storage, it's as cheap as you can get without actually stealing another vector. If `Val` is not moveable you don't lose anything by casting it to an rvalue. The nice thing about this type of function signature is that the caller can decide whether they want a copy or a move.

```
// Consider the difference of these calls
Val v;
fun(v);
fun(std::move v);
```

The first will call `Val`'s copy constructor if present, or fail to compile otherwise. The second will call the move constructor if present, or the copy constructor otherwise. It will not compile if neither is present.